# BASH scripting sorting by date

Tags: bash, sorting, date

I'm new to scripting in bash and our professor had us sort a file in this format

```
peas|10.00|05 Apr 2012
pea soup|10.00|05 Jan 2012
ham|10.00|06 Apr 2012
```

using the date on the third field, with the most recent item appearing on top.
I've tried using combinations of filters and sort but they didn't work. Can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 16):

try

```
sort  -t '|' -k 3.8,3.11nr  -k 3.4,3.6Mr -k 3.1,3.2nr < input
      ------ -------------  ------------ ------------
      sep    first key      second key   third key
```

Comment: Pretty cool.  Just for the record, month sort is GNU specific feature.  It may not work in other Unices.

Comment: awesome man, I was also able to use this to sort other item formats. Thanks!

Comment: @segfaulter09 Please consider accept this answer, if it's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat input.txt | awk -F '|' '{sprintf("date +%%s -d \"%s\"", $3) | getline tm}; {print tm "\t" $0}' | sort | cut -f2-
pea soup|10.00|05 Jan 2012
peas|10.00|05 Apr 2012
ham|10.00|06 Apr 2012
```

---

If you don't want call external command `date`,
you can write a custom `mktime2` function in `awk`:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
# script.awk

BEGIN {
    FS="|"
    m["Jan"] = "01"
    m["Feb"] = "02"
    m["Mar"] = "03"
    m["Apr"] = "04"
    m["May"] = "05"
    m["Jun"] = "06"
    m["Jul"] = "07"
    m["Aug"] = "08"
    m["Sep"] = "09"
    m["Oct"] = "10"
    m["Nov"] = "11"
    m["Dec"] = "12"
}

{
    print mktime2($3) "\t" $0 | "sort | cut -f2-"
}

function mktime2(s,    arr,yyyy,mm,dd)
{
    split(s, arr, " ")
    yyyy = arr[3]
    mm = m[arr[2]]
    dd = arr[1]
    return mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s 00 00 00", yyyy, mm, dd))
}
```

---

```
# make script executable
$ chmod +x script.awk

# run the script
$ ./script.awk input.txt
pea soup|10.00|05 Jan 2012
peas|10.00|05 Apr 2012
ham|10.00|06 Apr 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you (GNU sort):

```
 sort -t'|' -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.4,3.6Mr -k3.1,3.2nr file
```

Or (if you don't have GNU sort):

```
sed '1{x;s/^/Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;x};G;s/\(.*|\(..\) \(...\) \(....\)\)\n.*\3\(..\).*/\4\5\2 \1/' file
sort -nr |
sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to kev's answer, here's one that doesn't use `awk`

```
while IFS=\| read -r item price date ; do printf '%s|%s|%s|%s\n' "$(date +%s -d "$date")" "$item" "$price" "$date" ; done < table.txt | sort -n -t\| | cut -d\| -f2-
```

The idea is to add a field `sort` can use, sort by it, then strip it.

Comment: this technique is called a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)